# Append Dictionary type to Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I am very new to Swift, I am converting my Objective-C code to Swift these days.

I declared these properties:

```
private var startLocation: UInt?
private var rangeIndex: UInt?
private var transaction: Array<Dictionary<String, UInt>>?
var location: UInt?
```

While attempting to add a `Dictionary` type into the transaction array, the compiler warns me.

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([String: UInt?])'

```
func beginTransaction() -> Void {
    var transaction: Dictionary = ["rangeIndex": self.rangeIndex,
                                     "location": self.location,
                                "startLocation": self.startLocation]
    self.transaction?.append(transaction) //Warn: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([String: UInt?])'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!`to `self.rangeIndex`,`self.location` and `self.startLocation` as an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional, the warning will then disappear.

```
func beginTransaction() -> Void {
    var transaction: Dictionary = ["rangeIndex": self.rangeIndex!,
                                     "location": self.location!,
                                "startLocation": self.startLocation!]
    self.transaction?.append(transaction)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your array is `<String, UInt>` but you append `<String, UInt?>`

make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This warning has been said very clearly: the dictionary's value inside the `transaction` is `UInt` and it can not be nil. BUT your `startLocation` 、`rangeIndex`、`location` may be nil.